# I'm writing a chrome extension that plays an audio when you click the browser action but I can't get it to stop playing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The extension doesn't stop playing even with myAudio.pause in the code.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

  var myAudio = new Audio();
  myAudio.src = "music.mp3";
  myAudio.play();

  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(untab) {
    myAudio.pause();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a listener does not remove the previous one.

What happens on the first click?

- The first listener is run, `myAudio` is created and started.
- A second listener is added, with `myAudio` bound by a closure. Let's call it `myAudio1`.
- Since `myAudio` is local to the first listener, this reference is discarded.

What happens on the second click?

- The first listener is run, creating a (new) `myAudio`.
- A third listener is added, with `myAudio` bound by a closure. Let's call it `myAudio2`.
- Since `myAudio` is local to the first listener, this reference is discarded.
- The second listener is run, pausing `myAudio1`.

And things just get worse from there.

Instead of dynamically adding listeners, you should just keep state information. In case of a persistent background page, you can just keep a variable set - but note that it should not be local to the listener. Alternatively, you can keep it in `chrome.storage`.

```
var myAudio = new Audio(); // Gotta be global
myAudio.src = "music.mp3";

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  /* How you set up shouldPlay is up to you, it's a placeholder */
  if(shouldPlay) {
    myAudio.currentTime = 0; // Rewind if needed
    myAudio.play();
  } else {
    myAudio.pause();
  }
});
```

Comment: I tweaked the code but I'm not sure how exactly should I configure shouldPlay. Should it be in the function? And what should I set it to?